# How to assign a plot to a variable and use the variable in a multiplot in Python

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, subplot, figure

I would like to have a function which create a plot. Once I have the plot, I would like to use that in a multiplot.

For example, I could create the following function:

```
def fig_1(x):
    # create a new figure
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([1*x, 2*x, 3*x, 4*x])
    return fig
```

after that I would like something like:

```
subplot(3,2,1) = fig_1(1)
subplot(3,2,2) = fig_1(2)
subplot(3,2,3) = fig_1(3)
subplot(3,2,4) = fig_1(4)
subplot(3,2,5) = fig_1(5)
subplot(3,2,6) = fig_1(6)
```

In order to plot the final plot:

```
from pylab import *
pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("Cal8010.pdf")
for fig in xrange(1,figure().number):
```

In this way, it does not work. Could I do what I have in mind?

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

First: I create subplots and in each one a plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def fig_1(ax, x, y):
    ax.plot(x, y)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2)

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        x = np.random.random(10)
        y = np.random.random(10)
        fig_1(ax[i, j], x, y)
        ax[i, j].set_title(f"Subplot #{2*i + j + 1}")

plt.show()
```

Now, you can also plot an empty array and further update datas to this plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def fig_1(ax):
    line, = ax.plot([], [])
    return line


fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2)

lines = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        x = np.random.random(10)
        y = np.random.random(10)
        lines.append((fig_1(ax[i, j]), x, y))
        ax[i, j].set_title(f"Subplot #{2*i + j + 1}")        

for p in lines:
    l, x, y = p
    l.set_xdata(x)
    l.set_ydata(y)


fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.flush_events()

plt.show()
```

but this could be tricky because both axis on each plot are not adapted to the datas so plots can be out of bounds (so you possibly need to fix the x and y limits to min and max of datas)

Comment: Dear all, Dear David. I would prefer to have an independent function. I mean, in your example the function depends from  "fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2)". However, I think that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Reviewer,

here the solution that I have work out thanks to another post that I hope to find again in order to give the right credit to it.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)

def plot_ff(ax=None,data):
   ax.plot(data)
   return

plot_ff(axs[0, 0],data_1)
plot_ff(axs[0, 1],data_2)
plot_ff(axs[1, 0],data_3)
plot_ff(axs[0, 1],data_3)
```

In this way, it works and it is easily manage with different type of multiplot

What do you think about this solution? 
Should I erase this questions?
Diego